# CGI is inefficient, but what is being used that is so different nowaydays?

Tags: php, cgi

My understanding is that creating CGI scripts is a thing of a past, and has deemed inefficient because of the way it forks every time its being called. However I don't see what the different is considering when you call a web page with php scripts embeded, it still in some way forks to another process, so why is CGI deemed inefficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two "mainstream" ways around forking for every request:

1. You can load the interpreter directly into your server's process space, and prefork a number of set instances during startup.  mod_php and mod_python take roughly this tactic.
2. You can create a persistent process for the interpreter, and then either prefork or spawn threads for each request, communicating with the server over sockets.  FastCGI is used this way.

Event-driven servers, while not exactly mainstream, are becoming more common for good reason.  They rely on the knowledge that most websites spend most of their time blocking on I/O, just spinning their metaphorical gears.  Whenever a request needs to do any I/O, the server is free to start handling another request without starting another thread/process by using select() and friends.  This is really the only way to solve the [C10k problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

Comment: I'm not really sure this post is correct. First FCGI doesn't spawn threads in the case of PHP, it still forks. The only change is that the PHP instance it external (via FCGI) from the web-server so the web server can safely run as a single event driven thread. This event driven type of handling the requests allow for much cheaper handling of non-dynamic requests. So that only dynamic requests require a dedicated PHP instance, instead of each connection.

Comment: I confess to not being entirely familiar with how PHP specifically deals with this, but the FastCGI implementations I've seen do work this way.  However, I've updated the answer to generalize a bit.

Answer (score 2):

CGI forks every request. This means the "weight" of forking/initializing is done every time.

[FCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) or mod_php only fork on server start or on load increase. This means setup is only done once per process (but they don't share memory).

Facebook's [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/) doesn't fork (it transforms the PHP into thread-safe C++ code). This allows all the PHP "process" to live in a single multithreaded C++ binary, resulting in a substantial speed up and decrease in memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

There is FastCGI, when you start some instances of the php binary, and they handle queries one after another, this way those processes do not start over and over again for each request.

Also PHP is typically run as apache module, which has a lifecycle tied to the webserver, so no additional overhead between handling requests, when Apache identifies a file as PHP script it calls **mod_php** which was started togather with the webserver itself.

Answer (score 1):

CGI's overhead was mainly from having to `fork()` the webserver process handling the request, firing up a shell, and then running an external program.

Since the request was an external program, almost everying to do with the request had to be copied into the new shell's environment variables - query string, remote address, authentication data, etc.. POST data was passed to the script via its stdin. All of this took time to copy and configure, adding to the overhead.

This is one reason why query strings had to be length limited. Some operating systems had (and still do) length limits on the name of environment variables, and definitely had limits on how large an individual variable's contents could be. The HTTP spec itself has no limits, but because of the CGI mechanism and underlying OS limits, limited length query strings became the norm.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft IIS allows the script to be interpreted in-process by loading a library into its address space. (Newer versions of IIS work more like FastCGI in that the actual script execution is performed in a separate web worker process, although this is subject to the configuration settings for the virtual directory.)